# Any method to detect extremely weak electromagnetic wave signal? (10^12Hz, level ~10^(-28) Watt per meter^2 per Hz)

Tags: optics, electromagnetic-radiation, quantum-optics, signal-processing, sensor

Could you please let me know whether there is any method on the Earth to detect some EXTREMELY weak electromagnetic wave signal,

if it is a planar wave,

if its exact waveform is completely known (for both time and frequency domain),

if there is no environment noise at all,

if its energy flux density (per Hz) is only 10^(-28) Watt per meter^2 per Hz,

if its frequency is in 10^12 Hz with bandwidth of about 10^12 Hz,

if such EM signal appears in the region within around ~ 1 meter^3,

if its duration can be very short as seconds?

Any method to detect, to amplify, to extrat such EM signal? thanks.

Comment: If its exact waveform is completely known, why is the bandwidth so large?

Comment: @probably_someone Why shouldn't it be large? it is easy to define "simple looking" periodic wave forms where the bandwidth is infinite.

Comment: @probably_someone hi, if the signal has freq components from 1THz to 2THz :))), with known particular waveform :))))

Comment: Just an order of magnitude estimate here:  In space the smallest fields we can measure are ~1 $\mu$V/m and ~1 pT, which would correspond to a Poynting flux of ~$8 \times 10^{-13}$ W/$m^{2}$.  This is at much much lower frequencies (i.e., below 1 kHz) but if it were at 1 THz, then the frequency normalized Poynting flux would be ~$8 \times 10^{-25}$ W/$m^{2}$.  Huge caveat here is that the SNR drops precipitously at higher frequencies for these instruments and I'm not sure how well they could adjust this in the THz range...